# Configuration Error on roleManager in web.config on subdirectory

Tags: asp.net

I am getting an error in my `web.config` file  at `<rolemanager enabled="false">` can any one tell how to resolve this

[image]

Comment: Edit that title! It says nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your virtual directory is configured as an application in IIS.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis-7/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not created virtual directory. just create a virtual directory by going to IIS Manager

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the screen shot, **you have a second web.config in a subdirectory**.

In this web.config **you are not allowed to add this lines**, except if you make this subdirectory a new web application, something that I do not suggest to.

So you can not add this commands on the subdirectories web.config, only on root. To handle some special events in the subdirectories you need to use the code behind and a little programming.